# sliding imageview to reveal other images

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, slider

I have an ImageView X that starts out in `match_parent` mode. But when the user slides the image X, I want X to move to the left and allow image Z to display as well. If the user slides some more, I want image X to move a bit more to the left to allow both Y and Z to show as well.

Image X and the revelation of the other two images (Y and Z) must follow the touch of the user (at least crudely).

So basically I am looking for a slider. I have been working with the codes at http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-gestures.html but I am not getting much luck. I imagine this is about three imageViews and so should be simple enough. But here I am. Will someone please share such a code?

Note: the images are arranged as XYZ. Sliding X by 25% reveals XZ; sliding X by 50% reveals XYZ

EDIT:

A bit of detail is that I have a number of Image X (call them Xs) in a tableLayout that I build as a class inside the activity class. To fill the table, I am using AsyncTask `doInBackground`. As stated above, each X should be slide-able.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use a ViewPager to achieve the required effect.

Then you will pass the images that you want to display in the viewPagerAdapter and they will change as the the user swipes left or right.

Check this reference from Google: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Also check this tutorial for viewpager to create an Image Gallery:
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the links. But in my post, image X never leaves the screen. It simply moves over to let Z appear and then move over some more to let Y appear.

Answer (score 0):

let's try to custom your view pager or gallery . see the sample here but you need to custom more : https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow